# Omit Excel error when importing data into worksheet using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm writing one Perl script to generate excel report by spooling data from MySQL table.My script is working fine but,in the final report i see `number stored as text error` in one of the columns.Actually that column has number but appended with **dollar($)** sign.
Is there any ways to handle this error in perl script itself.

**Error screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be writing the value as a number but formatting as a dollar amount.

It would look something like this.

```
my $num = $workbook->add_format();
$num->set_num_format('$0.00');
```

Then, when you actually set the value:

```
$workbook->write($row, $col, $value, $num);
```

Alternatively, you can format an entire column, which would allow you to use write_row without having explicitly declare the format on each write.

```
$workbook->set_column($from_col, $thru_col, $width, $num);
```

Also, for what it's worth, [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) is the newer incarnation of [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel).